# Deleting rows from 3 tables in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I've got 3 tables (I'll mention only attributes that are needed):

**import**
`id`, `date`

**import_head**
`id`, `import_id`

**import_body**
`id`, `import_head_id`

`import_head` and `import_body` create one import item, import is created by dozens of import item
Relations: *import* **1** <==> **N** *import_head* **1** <==> **1** *import_body* (ON DELETE CASCADE on every relation)

**How can delete all import items when deleting row from import table?**

When deleting import using `DELETE FROM import WHERE id = ?` error is thrown: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` - on `import_head_id`

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed entities in DB, so now there are only two tables:

`import`
`import_item`

I haven't found anything better, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Modify foreign key at child table and make when delete (CASCADE)
This should work for you

Comment: Thanks for reply. Modify to what? Every is set to CASCADE when deleting.

Comment: Do you try to delete id which is not exist in one of your tables ?

Comment: No, I does exist. I have checked it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the records for the associated tables, before deleting the record from the primary key table. I would personally avoid `cascade` delete, because of performance implications, but it is your decision. [Here is a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525191/is-sql-server-dri-on-delete-cascade-slow) talking about issues with `cascade`.

Comment: Thanks a for reply. Well yes, I'm aware of this solution but I'd like to delete everything using one query (I'm using Doctrine2's remove function)