# DELETE FROM table becomes heavy as the number of records in table's children increase

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a main table called `Campaign`. Campaign's Id is a foreign key in another table `CampaignRun` and CampaignRun's Id is a foreign key in a third table `CampaignRecipient`. Due to my CASCADE requirements I am using

```
DELETE FROM Campaign WHERE Id = x
```

to remove all the associated information about a campaign. But this function becomes very heavy on the server and of course locks the tables while running. I was wondering if there is a faster way of dealing with `DELETE FROM`. `TRUNCATE` is faster but it unfortunately accepts no condition.

Will appreciate any working suggestions.

Comment: I would do the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1433231/1232818

Comment: I'd suggest you create a `temp` table and insert `ID's` of the records needs to be deleted to temp table and using `cursor` to delete them.It'll be much faster then just using `cursor` on a main table.

Comment: I would stop using CASCADE, to be honest. Delete the children in batches, and then delete the parent.

Comment: You could do 3 separate `deletes` in a transaction in the Bottom up order. I.e Delete the affected rows in `CampaignRecipient` then `CampaignRun` and then `Campaign`. Might cause lesser lockings and should be quicker IMO.

Comment: If we delete the record from PARENT table, MSSQL will delete the records from CHILD table. So, Just delete record from your PARENT table- Campaign.

Comment: @PareshJ That's exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Use Temp table to get all records you dont want to delete and then truncate the PARENT table and transfer the data from Temp table. DO the same for references table too.

Comment: But simultaneously another process might be writing into those tables, so isn't this quite risky?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.interrupt) out, interrupt() might be the answer